# 5V to 3.3V regualtor

Tags: esp8266

Please see below schematic, Which one is suitable for supply ESP8266 MCU

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] to include a link to the datasheet for the AMS1117-3.3. That should tell you.

Comment: The caps required will depend primarily on the AMS1117-3.3, not the ESP8266. The datasheet should provide guidance on what caps you need.

Answer (score 2):

The datasheet says that 22uF is always adequate as an output capacitor, and warns against using more than 1000uF.  The ideal size of the input capacitor will depend on the 5V source.  At face value, either circuit should be ok.

Comment: ok i got the point

Answer (score 0):

Either one should work however do as Transistor suggested, look up the actual device you are using and check its data sheet. I tried and found several different recommendations for the AMS117-3-3. You exceeded the requirements with both designs. On the input bulk capacitors I like to double up on them that way if one fails the other will keep on going and the user will never know. Keep the leads as short as possible and the high frequency bypass as close to the regulator leads as possible.